# How can I pass an argument of a dynamic type to a function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that receives an argument of a specific class type, but I want to make it dynamic so that I could pass the argument from another class name as well.

```
func unselectedTopCell(cell: SearchExploreCollectionViewCell) {
    let color = UIColor.init(named: "textBlack") ?? .black
    let borderColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.12)
    let textColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.87)
    cell.cellBGView?.borderColor = borderColor
    cell.cellBGView?.borderWidth1 = 1
    cell.titleLabel?.textColor = textColor
}
```

Now I want to reuse this function for another collection view cell, but how would I pass other class name instead of "SearchExploreCollectionViewCell" at calling time?

Comment: Does `SearchExploreCollectionViewCell` has the same variables? `cellBGView` for example.

Comment: Create a base class of the cell class and then inherit to both classes. Or create subclass of UIView/ UILabel and set property and set this class to view/label.

Comment: look up "protocol" and also generic types, these may provide a solution for you.

Comment: Use generics...and why are you passing a cell as parameter? You can create an extension of `UICollectionViewCell` and extend the functionality of unselectedTopCell() and call it.

Comment: but outlets are different as each class holds its own IBOutlets but elements are same

Answer (score 0):

Conform the classes you are going to pass as arguments under a common protocol. By doing so, you can give the argument's datatype as the protocol and any class that conforms to that protocol can be used in its place.

Comment: I don't have an exact code in hand now, but I'll try giving you an outline. While defining the class SearchExploreCollectionViewCell add a protocol, say CollectionViewCellProtocol. And for all the collection view cell classes use this protocol. Now while using the function,                                                               
    func unselectedTopCell(cell: CollectionViewCellProtocol) ....use like this. Any class conforming to that protocol can be used in that argument's place.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Hi @Community, your comment is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411139/community-user-posting-comments). Mind explaining why you wrote this comment on meta?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can fix this:

First, you can write an extension for it. It makes it a lot easier.

```
public extension UICollectionView {
   func cellWithIdentifierAndIndexPath<T:UICollectionViewCell>(cell:T.Type,indexPath:IndexPath) -> T {

        let genericCell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.className, for: indexPath) as! T
        return genericCell
    }
}
```

Then, inside your cellForItemAt function:

```
var cell = UICollectionViewCell()

switch yourCellType {
    case searchExplore:
       cell = collectionView.cellWithIdentifierAndIndexPath(cell: SearchExploreCollectionViewCell.self, indexPath: indexPath)
    case someThingElse:
       cell = collectionView.cellWithIdentifierAndIndexPath(cell: SomeThingElse.self, indexPath: indexPath)
    default:
       cell = collectionView.cellWithIdentifierAndIndexPath(cell: NoDataCell.self, indexPath: indexPath)
}
return cell
```

Important note: do not forget to set the cell's reusable id as the cell's class name.

For example, if you have a cell that have a name like "NoDataCell", you should use "NoDataCell" as its reuse identifier.